# I am trying to create new schema in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a new schema in SQL Developer:

```
CREATE USER admindba
  IDENTIFIED BY pwd4dba
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE tbs_perm_01
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tbs_temp_01
  QUOTA 20M on tbs_perm_01;
```

I am getting error

> SQL Error: ORA-00959: tablespace 'TBS_PERM_01' does not exist
>   00959. 00000 -  "tablespace '%s' does not exist"

What is wrong? Can anyone clear the error?

Comment: Seems that the `TBS_PERM_01` tablespace just doesn't exist. Are you sure you spelled it properly?

Comment: What's unclear about "*tablespace 'TBS_PERM_01' does not exist*"?

Comment: View > DBA. Add your connection. Connect. Expand tree. Go to security page. Click on users. Right click, create new. Nice dialog to help you there if you need it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. i found out the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think, following steps will help you.

1. Login as sysdba in oracle developer.
2. Execute the create user statement. For example, create a new user named ***smith*** with a password of ***password*** as follows:

   ```
   CREATE USER smith IDENTIFIED BY password;
   ```
3. Grant specific access to the new schema user. For example:

   ```
   GRANT CREATE TABLE TO smith;
   ```

   (Or this one to give all privileges to this user )

   ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO smith;
   ```
4. Verify schema creation. For example, use the following query for new user smith:

   ```
   SELECT username, account_status FROM dba_users
   WHERE username = 'SMITH';
   ```
5. Then login as ***smith***

I refer from this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbp/creating-database-schemas.html#GUID-8E89EF2D-1ED9-43BB-8B74-43D46A5B2B30)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the tablespace first. Example:

create tablespace tbs_perm_01 datafile '/path/to/data/mydatafile01.dbf' size 1G autoextend on;

You will likely have create the temporary tablespace too. Then you can create the user that will use those tablespaces.

Answer (score 0):

connect as sys to your server and check tablespaces
it looks that the tablespace  TBS_PERM_01 is missing

```
select * from dba_tablespaces

select * from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name = 'TBS_PERM_01'
```